# How to prevent win10Toast notifications from disappearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I want to send windows notification about some important message via python. I have tried `win10Toast`, but notifications disappear after program is finished.

My code is:

```
## program to generate a simple toast notifier
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
## instantiating the class
n = ToastNotifier()
n.show_toast("Test Message","Notification body",duration=15)`
```

It runs fine as long as my program is running, but it disappears after the program is finished. I want to show this message in system tray until user discards this message.

Secondly can you please tell me how to see notification history?

I am using Python 3.7 and Windows 10

Comment: There is a Library called win10toast_persist which is a fork of win10toast.
You can install it with `pip install win10toast-persist` [This is there PyPI Website](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast-persist/)

Comment: Ok, thanks I will check

Comment: @fm-sys Even with that module, the notification still disappears from the notification bar after the program terminates.

Answer (score -1):

change "duration=15" for 'duration=None

Comment: from win10toast import ToastNotifier
## instantiating the class
n = ToastNotifier()
n.show_toast("Test Message","Notification body",duration=None) it is giving following error message TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)